# Host Unresolved Android

Tags: android, dns, android-emulator

In Android emulator I encounter "Connection is lost.Host is Unresolved" error while communicating with server (creating `websocket`) if `URL` string is used. instead if `IP address` and `port` number is used  it works fine. 
I have configured it in host file of my `ubuntu powered pc`. It pings and all from the desktop.

any ideas?

Comment: is your dns working properly

Comment: no i suppose. But i have passed this command line argument for emulator -dns-server  10.0.0.1 and it says in console               [2014-05-23 17:56:23 - Emulator] DNS server name '10.0.0.1' resolved to 10.0.0.1:55                                                               Of course dns is working on my pc. Have even listed the url and ip address mapping in hosts file . entry in dconf editor , ip address as well as the url.

Comment: I changed the etc/hosts file of the emulator, which resolved the issue.

Comment: then answer your own question and accept it that way you will be helping others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the emulator skips the systems hosts file, change the etc/hosts file of the emulator, follow this link
http://eclecticdreams.com/blog/getting-a-hosts-file-onto-an-android-emulator

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the common problems appear in android's native emulator. To resolve this, you need to restart the emulator. Or debug your application on a real device.

As an alternate, I would also like to draw your attention towards [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) which offers very stable, reliable and fast android emulators ranging from different device profiles and API versions.

Comment: as per your recommendation installed genymotion. the error persists.

Comment: Go to command prompt and execute `nslookup your_domain_name` and see if it can translate your domain name into IP address. If it doesn't then your dns is expired or needs to be updated.

Comment: Can we change the etc/hosts file of genymotion?

Comment: I don't think its possible. Make sure your network's DNS server address is configured correctly